# C# Console Date Input

Tags: c#, date, console

C# Console App...
How can user give his birth date in preformat string "  /  /    " (Date/Month/Year) at the same line;
Is possible to recheck or change values in string before next procedure;
Thanks a lot...

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Mr. Akbar. Thanks for your code. When dateInput is e.x. 15/5/2015 is ok, but when dateInput is e.x. 15/12/1975 catch the error...;;;

Answer (score 0):

hi you must use split Like this

```
 Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your DateTime: \n");
            //you input your string dateTime Like 2/12/2013

            string DateInput = Console.ReadLine();

            //split it
            string[] DateTimeArray = DateInput.Split('/');

            //String DateTime 
            string ResultStringDateTime="";

            //this loop is for create string DateTime with Type Like 2-12-2013
            for (int i = 0; i < DateTimeArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i==2)
                {
                    ResultStringDateTime += DateTimeArray[i];
                    continue;
                }
                ResultStringDateTime += DateTimeArray[i]+"-";
            }

            //if u want change you must change in this line 

            //this is DateTime Type Of your DateTime 
            DateTime myDate;

            //in this step if you have error this will be message else create date time 
            try
            {

                //out String DateTime
                myDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ResultStringDateTime);
                Console.WriteLine(myDate.ToShortDateString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("err "+e.Message );
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

I hope Will Help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "recheck or change values" for a specified DateTime, i would suggest you to use this code:

```
Console.Write("Enter a date:");
string input = Console.ReadLine(), format = "";

try
{
    if (input.Contains("-"))
    {
        format = "dd-MM-yyyy";
    }
    else if (input.Contains("/"))
    {
        format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    }
    else if (input.Contains("."))
    {
        format = "dd.MM.yyyy";
    }
    else if (input.Contains(" "))
    {
        format = "dd MM yyyy";
    }

    DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(input, format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Console.WriteLine(date.ToShortDateString());
}
catch (Exception) { }

Console.ReadLine();
```

---

With this codesnip you can use any input you want...

> DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("2009-05-08 14:40:52,531", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

...you will just need to change the format form "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff" to your wished format.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter day of birth");
        DateTime dayOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
```

Now you can manipulate your time.